# SQL - Average x per y, per z

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partition-by

I have a data set of two columns, an ID and a datetime

I am trying to get an **average** *count* of hours *per ID* each month.

So far I have managed to use this code to get me the count of hours for an individual day:

```
SELECT
    id,
    DATE(created),
    DATE_PART(hour, created)::int AS "hour",
    --Counts 15 minute windows of activity
    FLOOR(DATE_PART(minute, created) / 15) AS "15 mins",
    (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id,
            DATE(created)) / 4.0) AS "Online Hours"
FROM
--The temporary table I pulled the data into
    #tempres
GROUP BY
    id,
    DATE(created),
    DATE_PART(hour, created),
    FLOOR(DATE_PART(minute, created) / 15)
ORDER BY
    id DESC,
    DATE(created),
    "hour" ASC,
    "15 mins" ASC;
```

But I've not been able to figure out how to apply AVG over the windowed function to get the monthly result.

This [Mockaroo link](https://www.mockaroo.com/11298a70) should produce the same kind of data I'm using.

I am aware that this is probably not the most streamlined starting point, so I'm very open to any other ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have come up with a mostly functional query.

By chucking the old query into a CTE I'm able to run the averaging aggregate function on it over a monthly time period.

*Still very open to cleaner options, but I thought I would put what I had here.*

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        MAX(created) AS "created",
        DATE_PART(month,
            created) AS "month",
        DATE(created) AS "day",
        DATE_PART(hour,
            created)::int AS "hour",
        FLOOR(DATE_PART(minute,
                created) / 15) AS "15_mins",
        COUNT(id),
        (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id,
                DATE(created)) / 4.0) AS "online_hours"
    FROM
        #tempres
    GROUP BY
        id,
        DATE_PART(month,
        created),
        DATE(created),
        DATE_PART(hour,
        created),
        FLOOR(DATE_PART(minute,
        created) / 15)
        ORDER BY
            id DESC,
            DATE(created),
            "hour" ASC,
            "15_mins" ASC
) SELECT
    id,
    DATE_PART(year, cte.created) AS "Year",
    cte.month,
    ROUND(AVG(online_hours), 2) AS "Average Hours"
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    id,
    DATE_PART(year, cte.created),
    cte.month
ORDER BY
    id,
    DATE_PART(year, cte.created),
    cte.month;
```